# Protobuf-net Serializing Parent Class inherited object property marked as [ProtoIgnore()] throwing "No serializer defined for type: System.Object"

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

All the objects in our system inherit a base class which has got a property of type object.

I have tried adding protoignore attribute to all the properties of the base class as well but that doesn't seem to work as well.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.BodyStyleDescription = "4x4";
        vehicle.BodyStyleText = "Prestige Medium";

        dynamic protobufModel = TypeModel.Create();
        AddTypeToModel<Vehicle>(protobufModel);

        using (MemoryStream compressed = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(compressed, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                protobufModel.Serialize(gzip, vehicle);
            }
            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(compressed.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(compressed.Length));
        }
    }

    public static MetaType AddTypeToModel<T>(RuntimeTypeModel typeModel)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).OrderBy(name => name);
        return typeModel.Add(typeof(T), true).Add(properties.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Following is the hierarchy of the object

```
 public interface IObjectBaseClass
{
    [ProtoIgnore()]
    object Parent { get; set; }
    [ProtoIgnore()]
    bool IsSaved { get; set; }
    [ProtoIgnore()]
    string XmlAtLoad { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectBaseClass : IObjectBaseClass
{
    public ObjectBaseClass()
    {
    }

    [ProtoIgnore()]
    internal object _Parent;
    [ProtoIgnore()]
    internal bool _IsSaved;
    [ProtoIgnore()]

    internal string _XmlAtLoad;

    [ProtoIgnore()]
    public bool IsSaved
    {
        get { return _IsSaved; }
        set { _IsSaved = value; }
    }

    [ProtoIgnore()]
    public object Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; }
        set { _Parent = value; }
    }

    [ProtoIgnore()]
    public string XmlAtLoad
    {
        get { return _XmlAtLoad; }
        set { _XmlAtLoad = value; }
    }

}

public class Vehicle : ObjectBaseClass
{
    private string _BodyStyleText;
    private string _BodyStyleDescription;

    public string BodyStyleDescription
    {
        get { return _BodyStyleDescription; }
        set { _BodyStyleDescription = value; }
    }

    public string BodyStyleText
    {
        get { return _BodyStyleText; }
        set { _BodyStyleText = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you do `typeModel.Add(typeof(T), true).Add(properties.ToArray())` you are adding *all* properties of `T` to the runtime type model, including those marked with `ProtoIgnore`.  You can see this by calling the debugging method `protobufModel.GetSchema(typeof(Vehicle))` which returns:

> ```
> message Object {
> }
> message Vehicle {
>    optional string BodyStyleDescription = 1;
>    optional string BodyStyleText = 2;
>    optional bool IsSaved = 3;
>    optional Object Parent = 4;
>    optional string XmlAtLoad = 5;
> }
> ```

To avoid adding properties marked with `[ProtoIgnore]`, you could do:

```
    public static MetaType AddTypeToModel<T>(RuntimeTypeModel typeModel)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes<ProtoIgnoreAttribute>().Any())
            .Select(p => p.Name)
            .OrderBy(name => name);
        return typeModel.Add(typeof(T), true).Add(properties.ToArray());
    }
```

Alternatively, since you are manually annotating some of your models with protobuf attributes anyway, you could mark the derived types with `[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]`, e.g.:

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Vehicle : ObjectBaseClass
{
    private string _BodyStyleText;
    private string _BodyStyleDescription;

    public string BodyStyleDescription
    {
        get { return _BodyStyleDescription; }
        set { _BodyStyleDescription = value; }
    }

    public string BodyStyleText
    {
        get { return _BodyStyleText; }
        set { _BodyStyleText = value; }
    }
}
```

Using either method, the schema for `Vehicle` becomes:

> ```
> message Vehicle {
>    optional string BodyStyleDescription = 1;
>    optional string BodyStyleText = 2;
> }
> ```

This is what you require.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't know you could do protobufModel.GetSchema(typeof(Vehicle)) to debug which properties are being serialized. The changes you've provided works fine.